# Block specific URL in HAProxy / url-encoding

Tags: haproxy, access-control-list, regex, url

I'm trying to restrict access to a specific URL. It should not allowed to access /admin.php.

```
frontend example
  acl restricted_page path_beg -i /admin\.php
  http-request deny if restricted_page
```

This works fine, HAProxy is blocking access to this URL.
But when I enter http://example.org/ad%6Din.php (%6D = hexcode for "m"), HAProxy is not restricting access.

What is the best way to do this?

- Is there a option in HAProxy or do I need to specify a regluar expression matching "admin.php" as plaintext and/or url-encoded?
- Are there any other ways to bypass the restriction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it happens, HAProxy has a [converter](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#7.3.1-url_dec) to decode the field, making sure that your ACL will always match a given string.

> **url_dec**
>   Takes an url-encoded string provided as input and returns the
>   decoded version as output. The input and the output are of type
>   string.

You'd use it like this.

```
frontend example
  acl restricted_page path_beg,url_dec -i /admin.php
  http-request deny if restricted_page
```

Comment: For me, only this syntax worked (HAProxy Version: 1.8.8):
`acl restricted_page path,url_dec -m beg -i /admin.php`